# Do signature weapons ever become free?

Tags: far-cry-3

Just got the `Shredder` unlocked and am thinking about buying it. But I'm wondering if fixing towers will make it free later?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No sadly they do not. They will always cost money for the sole reason that they are the best weapons in the game!

Source-Passed Farcry 3

Hope that helps!
Charkz

Answer (score 1):

`Do signature weapons ever become free?` **No**

> Signature Weapons are usually unlocked by completing certain
>   objectives. After unlocking the weapon, they may be purchased from the
>   store or any self-service weapon locker. (Activating Radio Towers
>   cannot earn you free Signature Weapons, but activating all Radio Towers will unlock the Bushman)

---

**Unlocking the Shredder**

Vector .45 ACP (basic version)

> This weapon becomes free after deactivating 12 Radio Towers.

Shredder (signature version)

> A signature version named Shredder is available for purchase after the
>   player finds 10 Memory Cards.
>
> The weapon is not available for purchase until the player reaches the Southern Island, its signature version can be unlocked while still on the North Island

---

[**Shredder**](http://farcry.wikia.com/wiki/Shredder#Signature_Version)

[image: Shredder]

> It has a custom paint job, an Optic
>   Sight, a Suppressor, an extended 50-round magazine, enhanced accuracy
>   and damage, and costs $3275.

It is the most powerful  weapon you can own.

Comment: That is some expensive DLC

Comment: It's not a DLC :)

Answer (score 1):

Just to add, money will eventually become a non-issue. Therefore if you can afford the gun now, it will be a worthy investment (as will all the other signature weapons).

Answer (score -1):

Yes, after complete more than 
`80%` of your game all signature weapons will be free.If i'm not wrong, there are 4 signature weapons in farcry3.

Comment: This directly contradicts all of the existing answers, do you have any evidence of this?

Comment: I played farcry 3 more than 5 times   after going to hoyed's island  and discovering the ancient Knife this gun will unlock. Actually this is not directly depends on percentage of completed games this is depends **how many radio towers deactivated by a player**.

Comment: Again, I understand what you're saying, but it contradicts all the existing answers. I'll happily agree with you if you can actually show some evidence that what you're saying is correct. Bare in mind we're talking about the **Signature** weapon here, not the standard version.